# List item disclosure isn't firing inside a controller

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to get the item disclosure to work in a list item in Sencha Touch using a controller ref. But the event never seems to fire/receive inside controller. All of the examples I've seen have the list item using a listener but I thought that wasn't very MVC so I'm trying to do it this way (is there any reason why they use listeners instead of a controller?)

In my view, the list is an item inside the EnquiryIndex view.

When I do this in a console window it returns the list correctly so I know the ref is working ok:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query("enquiryindexview list")[0]
```

See below example:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.EnquiryIndex', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    requires: [

    ],

    config: {
        refs: {           
           enquiryIndexViewRef: 'enquiryindexview list'
        },

    control: {
        'enquiryIndexViewRef': {
            disclose: 'onDiscloseEnquiryIndex'
        }            
    }
},

onDiscloseEnquiryIndex: function (rec) {

   // never gets here!
}
```

});

Comment: what about doing '#enquiryindexview list' instead

Comment: I tried using 'itemtap' instead and this seems to work. Is there any reason why disclose doesn't work? What is the difference between the 2?

Comment: Does your list's config include, `onItemDisclosure : true`?

Comment: Also worth noting, *When any of the listeners returns false, the action (disclose) is cancelled.*

Comment: Josh, yes i have this in my config. Isnt that just to show the icon? Can you confirm that the icon press causes the event? Im not able to retest as yet. Please see my comment below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
config: {
  control: {
    'enquiryindexview list': {
      disclose: 'onDiscloseEnquiryIndex'
  }            
}
```

or this

```
config: {
  refs: {           
     enquiryIndexViewRef: 'enquiryindexview list'
  },

  control: {
    enquiryIndexViewRef: {
      disclose: 'onDiscloseEnquiryIndex'
  }            
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok what's the significance of not having the control ref in speech marks and what is the difference between disclose/itemtap?

Comment: Having your reference in the refs object allow you to call this.getMY_REF(). Not sure what other differences there are. Then the itemtap event will be fired when you tap the item (anywhere) and the disclosure event will be fired when your tap the arrow/disclosure item in the element.

Comment: Wait a minute, ive been assuming the disclosure was the same. I thought the icon would be too small to press to make it worthy of its own event. I'll re-test and get back to you. Reason i asked about speech marks is that my example was identical to yours apart from the marks and wasnt sure of difference. But i guess this is regular json...

Comment: I tested and the quotes make no difference. But I think your problem lies in the distinction between `itemtap` and `disclose`, as TDeBaileul pointed out. `disclose` is just for the arrow icon.

Comment: Ok I guess this was my misunderstanding of how the event was generated. I don't think clicking the icon is very usable on a phone being much smaller than the list item itself. I think itemtamp would be the better candidate for this. Thanks for help though.

Answer (score 0):

What you might have missed doing is adding this line in the app.js

`controllers: ['EnquiryIndex']`,

Try this out, it should work now.